# CakePHP sum of deep association

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

Consider the following models:

```
/* HerdsTable.php */
class HerdsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        ...
        $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
        $this->hasMany('Costs', [
            'foreignKey' => 'herd_id'
        ]);
        $this->hasMany('Feedings', [
            'foreignKey' => 'herd_id'
        ]);


/* FeedingsTable.php */
class FeedingsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        ...
        $this->belongsTo('Herds', [
            'foreignKey' => 'herd_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
        $this->hasMany('Feedingssupps', [
            'foreignKey' => 'feeding_id'
        ]);
    }

/* FeedingssuppsTable.php */
class FeedingssuppsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        ...
        $this->belongsTo('Feedings', [
            'foreignKey' => 'feeding_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
    }
```

So `herd has many feedings` and `feedings has many feedingssupps`

The `feedingssupps` has the following columns: `id, feeding_id, name, weight, dryweight, price`.

In my herd controller I would like to get the  SUM of `weight, dryweight, price`, grouped by `name`. But I can't figure it out.

This is what I came up with:

```
    $herd = $this->Herds->find()
        ->contain( 
        [
            'Costs', 
            'Feedings' =>
                ['Feedingssupps' => function ($q) use ($id)
                {
                    return $q
                        ->select(['Feedingssupps.feeding_id', 'total' => 'SUM(Feedingssupps.price)'])
                        ->group('Feedingssupps.name');
                }]
        ])
        ->where(['Herds.id'=> $id])
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What's the problem with the shown query? What exactly is it (programming wise) that you can't figure out?

Comment: The sum isnt in the results

Comment: Then you'll have to do some further debugging I'm afraid, start with checking the generated SQL queries, and test what values they actually do select. I could only shoot in the dark here, the only thing that catches my eye is that `feeding_id` is not selected as an aggregate, and probably not functionality dependent, so you might get wrong results when different foreign keys (`feeding_id`) are using the same name, as the group would contain multiple different foreign keys.